# The Video Thumbnails are not showing up in my recyclerView

Tags: java, android, video-thumbnails

I am working on a video player app. I'm able to retrieve all folders containing video files on the phone and also I displayed the title and the duration for each video in each folders but the thumbnail for each video doesn't display.

this the model class.

```
package com.example.videoplayer;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VideoFilesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<MediaFiles> videoFilesArraylist = new ArrayList<>();
    VideoFilesAdapter videoFilesAdapter;
    String folder_name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_files);
        folder_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("foldername");
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(folder_name);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.videos_rv);

        showVideoFiles();
    }

    private void showVideoFiles() {
        videoFilesArraylist = fetchMedia(folder_name);
        videoFilesAdapter = new VideoFilesAdapter(videoFilesArraylist, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(videoFilesAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        videoFilesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    private ArrayList<MediaFiles> fetchMedia(String folderName) {
        ArrayList<MediaFiles> videoFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " like?";
        String [] selectionArg = new String[]{"%" + folderName + "%"};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, selectionArg, null);

        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()){
            do{
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
                String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE));
                String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String size = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE));
                String duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION));
                String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
                String dateAdded = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED));

                MediaFiles mediaFiles = new MediaFiles(id, title, displayName, size, duration, path, dateAdded);

                videoFiles.add(mediaFiles);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return videoFiles;
    }
}
```

this is the adapter

```
package com.example.videoplayer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VideoFilesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoFilesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<MediaFiles> videoList;
    private Context context;

    public VideoFilesAdapter(ArrayList<MediaFiles> videoList, Context context) {
        this.videoList = videoList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.video_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.videoName.setText(videoList.get(position).getDisplayName());
        String size = videoList.get(position).getSize();
        holder.videoSize.setText(android.text.format.Formatter.formatFileSize(context, Long.parseLong(size)));
        //Video duration in milliseconds
        double videoDuration_in_ms = Double.parseDouble(videoList.get(position).getDuration());
        holder.videoDuration.setText(timeConversion((long) videoDuration_in_ms));

        // Getting the thumbnail
        Glide.with(context).load(new File(videoList.get(position).getPath())).into(holder.thumbnail);

        holder.menu_more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Menu more", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, VideoPlayerActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return videoList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView thumbnail;
        ImageView menu_more;
        TextView videoName;
        TextView videoSize;
        TextView videoDuration;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            menu_more = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_menu_more);
            videoName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_name);
            videoSize = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_size);
            videoDuration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_duration);
        }
    }
    //Convert from millisecond to minute and second
    public String timeConversion(long value){
        String videoTime;
        int duration = (int) value;

        //convert milliseonds to hour
        int hours = (duration/3600000);

        //convert milliseonds to minutes
        int minutes = (duration/60000) % 60000;

        //convert milliseonds to seconds
        int seconds = (duration % 60000) / 60000;

        if(hours > 0){
            videoTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
        } else {
            videoTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
        }

        return videoTime;
    }
}
```

this is the MediaFiles class

```
package com.example.videoplayer;

public class MediaFiles {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String displayName;
    private String size;
    private String duration;
    private String path;
    private String dateAdded;

    public MediaFiles(String id, String title, String displayName, String size, String duration, String path, String dateAdded) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.size = size;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.path = path;
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getDateAdded() {
        return dateAdded;
    }

    public void setDateAdded(String dateAdded) {
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }
}
```

I looked for some solutions and I found that one possible solution is to downgrade my targetSdk and compileSdk version. But it still does not appear.

Comment: Where are you changing the value of thumbnail?  I don't see anywhere where it is set

Comment: @CCT I guess is in the `Adapter#onBindView` call. `Glide.with(context).load(new File(videoList.get(position).getPath())).into(holder.thumbnail);`.

Comment: You might try MediaMetadataRetriever, for audio files I use metatdataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture() to get the album art

Comment: Could you show me an example please?